# Someone who enjoys downloading and maintaining files?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for someone who likes or loves downloading and uploading files?

An example: A designer who downloads resources and then catalogs them on a cloud drive.

Comment: Why would that be any different from a person who enjoys any activity??

Comment: Because it's specifically relating to those actions?

Comment: The answer you have chosen applies to just about any getting and keeping activity for things.

Comment: The answer fits my example, I have edited the title to better reflect my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **digital hoarder** is a neologism that refers to downloading and keeping files in various forms of storage for an indefinite time.

Here's an [article from WBUR titled "Are You a Digital Hoarder"](https://www.wbur.org/hereandnow/2012/04/12/digital-hoarder-computer) back in 2012 that describes the compulsive keeping of emails, music, photos, and other files:

> "I see people hoarding photos, movies, music files--that in truth they'll probably never look at again," he said.

Here's a more extended confession from an author writing for the Daily Beast in 2014, which features cloud storage as a central part of the hoarding habit, titled "[I'm a Digital Hoarder](https://www.thedailybeast.com/im-a-digital-hoarder)":

> But I hadn’t considered that basic tech skills could facilitate the hoarding instinct until a colleague saw the 46 subfolders in my webmail inbox. I was, she diagnosed, half joking and half horrified, a “digital hoarder.”
>
> And she knew nothing about my recent Dropbox and iCloud data storage purchases, necessary to relieve the strain on my hard drive, stuffed with gigabytes of photos (countless iPhone screenshots of brilliant—and brilliantly bad—Daily Mail headlines), videos (me serenading my roommate with an especially soulful rendition of “Leaving on a Jetplane”; my three-year-old nephew serenading me with his version of the Peter, Paul, and Mary classic), and podcasts that I can easily access on BBC Radio 4 but save to my Dropbox anyway. Or about my Google documents—dozens of them—containing research for stories I wrote two years ago, along with links to hundreds of stories I’ve clipped and catalogued, never to be pursued. And never to be deleted.

This term has been adopted with pride by some digital hoarders, who recognize the habit but seek to enable it. Case in point: this author in 2013 suggesting applications for keeping track of all of this digital data:

> [8 Essential Tools for the Digital Hoarder](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/8-essential-tools-for-the-digital-hoarder/)

The usage has continued into the present. For instance, the phenomenon of digital hoarding was reported on [by the BBC in a 2019 article](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20190104-are-you-a-digital-hoarder) (url includes "digital-hoarder"), though someone should perhaps tell them that the usage occurs before 2015:

> The term digital hoarding was first used in 2015 in a paper about a man in the Netherlands who took several thousand digital photos each day and spent hours processing them.

Comment: That fits the bill! Excellent answer and sources!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this person is creating a digital library.
From Wiki:

"A digital library, digital repository, or digital collection, is an online database of digital objects that can include text, still images, audio, video, or other digital media formats. Objects can consist of digitized content like print or photographs, as well as originally produced digital content like word processor files or social media posts. In addition to storing content, digital libraries provide means for organizing, searching, and retrieving the content contained in the collection."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_library

So, this person would be a "digital librarian"
Not quite a single word as requested.

Answer (score -1):

A **seeder** is someone who uploads (and downloads as well typically but not always)

A **leecher** is someone who downloads (typically only)

Comment: I'm not quite referring to someone who torrents. See my updated question.

Comment: Seeding and leeching are both terms used in torrenting, but are in no way exclusive to it.  A human being who is constantly taking things from people (food, utilities, belongings) is a leech, go ahead and check a dictionary ;)